# How to refresh a page when crossing a certain width threshold?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, refresh, window-resize

I'm looking to refresh (reload) the page when the user's window size gets to 570px. I'm building a responsive website and need to do this (I haven't got time to go into detail about the why).

Basically, what I'm looking for is for the webpage to refresh ONCE when the window size crosses 570px width (once when it gets smaller, and once when it gets bigger).

I know this isn't ideal and it's something that should be avoided, but for this particular site, it will solve all my problems.

Comment: Why do you need to reload the page? Is the content changing or only the layout? In this case why don't you set display:none; to the content that has to disappear?

Comment: it's got nothing to do with content, and CSS will not fix the issue. Like I said, it's probably not the best way of doing it, but for this particular build, it would save me a lot of time doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

I would not do this myself, but you can use the following on page load (or document ready):

```
var threshold = 570;
var initialDiff = ($(window).width() > threshold) ? 1:-1;

$(window).on('resize',function(e){
    var w = $(window).width();
    var currentDiff = w - threshold;
    if(currentDiff*initialDiff < 0) {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

This works in both directions.
See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/8T6R2/) for an example where the indicator div is highlighted when the width crosses the threshold.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! So far the best solution for refreshing on screen resizing passed a certain media query.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 if($(window).width()>570)
    location.reload();//reload current page
});
```